# Something and Nothing

Tags: existence, nothing

What is something and what is nothing. They both need each other to exist. Why is there something but not nothing?

Comment: "they both need each other" - quite the opposite, in fact: the two are mutually exclusive. "Nothing" means the lack of any "something".

Comment: Nothing came first, but as you say, something was missing.

Comment: The SEP article on Nothingness is great https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/nothingness/ Also see: 'What is "Nothing"?' discussion on here: https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/94046/what-is-nothing/94128#94128

Comment: @CriglCragl there is no article on somethingness.

Comment: @ScottRowe: Ontology? Or historically https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/substance/ There are lots of stances & schools on the nature of somethingness/es. Almost every major philosopher has distinct views, from extension, to noumena, to the world is all that is the case..

Comment: Nothing is the mystical or ineffable experience of the empty field of awareness which we paradoxically think of as something.  To speak of nothing is to evoke the distinction between nothing and something in the domain of arising concepts. In the domain of concepts there is what I call a distinction between nothing and something and in the empty field of awareness there is no arising distinction. The concept of mutually exclusive or dependent arises as another set of distinctions and consist of something.

Comment: @CriglCragl Everyone has something to say about everything and nothing. But does it mean anything? :-)

Comment: @SystemTheory: "The moon passes over the
ocean of non-being
Droplets of spray tear loose
and fall back
On the cresting waves
a million galaxies
Are a little scum
on that shoreless sea"

Comment: @ScottRowe: "Your outside is in when your inside is out
So come on (Woo!), come on (Woo!)
Come on, it's such a joy, come on, it's such a joy
Come on, let's make it easy, come on, let's make it easy
Make it easy (Woo!)
Make it easy (Woo!)
Everybody's got something to hide
Except for me and my monkey
Hey!
Yeah! Come on"

Comment: A fruitful discussion.

Comment: The universe (something) came out of nothing. Nothing is a big deal. How did nothing become something?

Answer (score 2):

Something is an unspecified thing. Nothing is the absence of things. The two words do not depend on each other; they have a shared dependency on the idea of thing.

Comment: In contrast to everything, which doesn't depend on anything.

Comment: @ScottRowe indeed, very succinctly put.

Comment: This is an excellent example of the etymological fallacy.

Comment: @ScottRowe: But it depends on every thing, so that includes anything..?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is what you can see of the unobservable universe.  One assumes it's there.  A case of nothing and something.

Answer (score 0):

There is something instead of nothing because there is a tiny, tiny asymmetry in the amount of matter and antimatter in the universe. After they annihilate, a tiny, tiny amount of ordinary matter is left over as surplus. This is why we are here.

Comment: Imagine how full the universe would have been if that didn't happen? No one would be asking why there is something instead of nothing.

Comment: @ScottRowe, because we... uh... would be radiation instead of matter. You know what they say- You matter- unless you light. Den you energy.