# What is the definition of nothingness?

Tags: reference-request, philosophy-of-physics, nothing

I am asking this question because I read Lawrence Krauss's book "A Universe from Nothing". I have also read a lot of criticism of that book, saying that Krauss's "nothingness" is actually something, namely a quantum vacuum. But that raises the question, what is the true definition of nothingness? Also, have any philosophers written about, and perhaps even tried to define, nothingness? I would love to see some references.

Comment: SEP is a good place to start as usual. https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/nothingness/

Comment: [lao-tsu uses](https://www.tao-te-king.org/11.htm) it as the "opposite of beingness", so: no-thingness=idea/use/value, beingness=matter/possession/profit, which does not/rarely mean "the absolute nothingness"  .."absolute nothingness" seems to be the(!) "ideal (no!) idea".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is "Nothing"?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/94046/what-is-nothing)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Many philosophers have written about *nothingness*, see
   [Nothingness](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/nothingness/).

   Best known for this subject is Heidegger in his book "Being and
   Time" (German original: Sein und Zeit). The German term for *the
   nothingness* is “das Nichts”.
2. The lingustic problem with the term *nothingsness* is that the term
   reifies the negation. To negate a statement does not create a new
   noun. And because there is no new noun, one cannot ask for
   properties of the noun *nothingness*.

   Therefore the main criticism of using the term *nothingness* is its
   tendency to create philosophical pseudo-problems.
3. Quantum fluctuations are a physical – not a philosophical – concept,
   see [Quantum fuctuations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_fluctuation). Quantum fluctuations are the
   spontaneous creation and annihilation of particles from the vacuum. I assume that’s what Krauss’ book speaks about.

   Quantum fluctuations play an important role in quantum field theory. They
   are considered the seed for structure formation in cosmology
   during the early time of our cosmos. See Alan Guth [Inflation and
   the New Era of High-Precision Cosmology](https://physics.mit.edu/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/physicsatmit_02_cosmology.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

If we go by "negation of everything", you essentially construct the set {P| P = ~Q, for all Q}, where P, Q are statements.

Interestingly, via Russels paradox the inconsistency of this set is swiftly established via the statement "The above set exists". It must contain its negation and its double negation.

If we go by logical independence, the second you construct a formal system that expresses Peano arithmetic, you will arive at statements that are not fully semantically encapsulated within the system itself. In that regard, from the perspective of the system the statements arise out of nothing, since there is no logical link between both.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).